# Shell variables in yq 4 using env()

Tags: shell, yq

I want to build a pipeline function that replaces a value in a yaml file. For that I want to make both the
pattern and the replacement value variable. I have seen the [env-variables-operators](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators) article in the yq docs, however I cannot find the relevant section.

I have a yaml file with the following content:

```yaml
---
spec:
  source:
    helm:
      parameters:
        - name: "image.tag"
          value: "1.0.0"
```

I now want to build a pipeline function that will replace the value of the `value` key in the yaml.
I can do so with:

```bash
$ yq '.spec.source.helm.parameters[0].value = "2.0.0"' myyaml.yml
---
spec:
  source:
    helm:
      parameters:
        - name: "image.tag"
          value: "2.0.0"
```

Now I want to make this command customizable.
What works:

```bash
$ VALUE=3.0.0
$ replacement=$VALUE yq '.spec.source.helm.parameters[0].value = env(replacement)' myyaml.yml
---
spec:
  source:
    helm:
      parameters:
        - name: "image.tag"
          value: "3.0.0"
```

What doesn't work

```bash
$ VALUE=3.0.0
$ PATTERN=.spec.source.helm.parameters[0].value
$ replacement=$VALUE pattern=$PATTERN yq 'env(pattern) = env(replacement)'
spec:
  source:
    helm:
      parameters:
        - name: "image.tag"
          value: "1.0.0"
```

I have also tried to use `strenv` and wrapping the replacement pattern in quotes, but it is not working.
Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import data with `env` but not code. You could inject it (note the changes in the quoting), but this is bad practice as it makes your script very vulnerable:

```bash
VALUE='3.0.0'
PATTERN='.spec.source.helm.parameters[0].value'
replacement="$VALUE" yq "${PATTERN} = env(replacement)" myyaml.yml
```

```yaml
---
spec:
  source:
    helm:
      parameters:
        - name: "image.tag"
          value: "3.0.0"
```

Better practice would be to import the path in a form that is interpretable by yq, e.g. as an array and using `setpath`:

```bash
VALUE='3.0.0'
PATTERN='["spec","source","helm","parameters",0,"value"]'
replacement="$VALUE" pattern="$PATTERN" yq 'setpath(env(pattern); env(replacement))' myyaml.yml
```